# mapView not loading in Container

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I've got a UIViewController that has a segmented controller, from this VC I have 2 containers.  container 1 loads a tableview and works great, container 2 has an MKMapView set up but does not load, just has  a blank screen when i  select the segment for it.

this is my TrackMapView code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit



class TrackMapView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0225,longitude: 72.5714)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "jim"
    annotation.subtitle = "smith"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

}



}
```

This is my segment code,

```
@IBAction func showContainer(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tableContainer.alpha = 1
            self.mapContainer.alpha = 0
        })

    }else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tableContainer.alpha = 0
            self.mapContainer.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}
```

The class is connected to the container in the storyboard correctly and the IBOutlets seem to be connected up in the right place.

TrackTableView (which works as expected)

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import FirebaseDatabase
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class TrackTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var TR: newTracks!
var track = [newTracks]()
var items: [newTracks] = []
var filteredTrack = [newTracks]()
var inSearchMode = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

    getTrackData()


}
```

There are a number of functions below this code also.

I don't have any Segue code in any of my ViewControllers, it is all done via storyboard.

Comment: Where have you declared `mapContainer`. Show the code.

Comment: in my main ViewController with the following

    "@IBOutlet weak var mapContainer: UIView!"
    "@IBOutlet weak var tableContainer: UIView!"

These are connected to the the respective containers in storyboard

Comment: How are you adding `TrackMapView` to `mapContainer`?

Answer (score 0):

ok this is resolved now.  I seemed to have an erroneous View below my mapview on the storyboard, deleted the mapView and the standalone view, re added the mapview and it is working fine.

Thanks for all input